# Как настроить vuejs и nodejs для работы с mssql

Tags: node.js, vue.js

Имеется установленный nodejs, vuejs, пакет mssql.. 
Имеется файл db.js для подключения к sql:

**UPDATED:**

```
const express = require('express') 
const app = express()
app.post('/api', function(req, res){
  res.send("<h2>Привет Express!</h2>")    
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080)
```

В Home.vue:

```
created() {
  this.$axios({        
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/api'
  }).then((result) => { console.log(result) })
```

}

Почему node.js мне возвращает "Cannot POST" (в консоле "localhost:8080/api 404 (Not Found)")?
Если кто понимает, объясните непутевому.

Comment: Так не получиться, потому что Home.vue работает на клиенте, а у клиента, собственно, нет доступа к mssql. Нужно подготовить данные на сервере и потом опрокинуть в клиент.

Первым делом глянуть сюды https://ssr.vuejs.org/ru/guide/#%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BFn%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B0-vue

Comment: @k0mar, как понять "Нужно подготовить данные на сервере и потом опрокинуть в клиент"?

Comment: Ща подготовлю ответ, минутку)

Comment: Дёргаешь с фронта ручку типа `/getData`, на серваке на этот роут вешаешь обработчик. Он (обработчик) идёт в базу, берёт нужную инфу и отдаёт фронту. На вью я такие вещи делаю в хуке `async created()`. В нём аксиосом дёргаю урл и `await`-ом жду результат. Ну а дальше распихиваю куда надо.

Comment: @AlexSazonov, а можно небольшой примерчик или ссылку с примером? "Дёргаешь с фронта ручку типа /getData" это роутинг на страницу я так понял? Чет сложно)) надо было api для работы с бд на php делать)

Comment: @Odyssey написал небольшой пример. Но если с пыхой до этого работал и хорошо и быстро можешь сделать там, то, наверное, лучше делать там :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently
И запускать примерно так(package.json):

```
"dev": "concurrently \"npm:dev:front\" \"npm:dev:back\"",
"dev:back": "nodemon src/server/index.js --watch",
"dev:front": "vue-cli-service serve --port 3000"
```

Comment: капец столько времени потратил, все завилось, спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Вообще советую почитать немного про [Express](https://expressjs.com/ru/starter/hello-world.html). А [тут](https://expressjs.com/ru/guide/database-integration.html) про интеграцию БД.

Вот тут сервер элементарный на экспресе

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/getInfo", function(req, res){
    // тут логика похода в бд
    res.send(infoFromDB);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Тут кусочек кода на клиенте. Предположим, что это компонент главной страницы.

```js
import axios from 'axios'; // но вот это лучше делать в main.js и там немного настроить baseURL и всё такое

// хук created
async created() {
  let data = await axios.get('http://server.address/getData');
  // в data кладётся инфа с сервера. Дальше уже раскидываем её куда хочется
}
```

Comment: спасибо тебе за пример. Попробовал, уже есть подвижки) Посмотри я обновил ^^. Вопрос теперь, почему node.js мне возвращает "Cannot POST" и в консоле  "http://localhost:8080/api 404 (Not Found)"? localhost:8080 это Home

Comment: @Odyssey а вот эта `process.env.PORT` переменная точно прописана?

Comment: я пробовал и так и так. просто 8080 оставлял.. Прочитал всю статью которую вы мне посоветовали.

Comment: Так, подожди. А разве метод `post` не предполагает нагрузки с собой? То есть инфы, которую мы постим? 404, конечно, заставляет задуматься, но тем не менее. В посте что мы отправляем? Тело запроса там не обязательно?

Comment: В общем, у меня в профиле есть телега. Завтра черкани туда. Поробуем решить. Странные дела.

Comment: попробовал и с get тоже самое. с телегой на работе не вариант( мне не понятен один момент, вот я аксиосом отправляю на localhost:8080/api (api от балды путь придумал) запрос, а в скрипте db.js  app.get ловит его, каким образом система понимает что необходимо посмотреть в db.js (Например в пыхе я конкретно указываю куда отправить, в существ-й серверный скрипт и там обрабатываю)?

Comment: @Odyssey, а как запускаешь сборку(client и server)?

Comment: @haswell, "dev": "vue-cli-service serve --port 3000".